# timeout + root password + strace in one line

Tags: command-line, root, strace

I'm trying to run a timeout command, with root password and strace all in one line, the original cmmand is

`sudo -S timeout 4 strace -p 2829 -f -e trace=write -s 9999`

but that promps for entering the root password. which I already have and wants to put it in one line, so this becomes

`echo ROOT_PASSWORD | sudo -S strace -p 2829 -f -e trace=write -s 9999`

I tried putting timeout in the front, middle or at the end but it doesn't work, such as

`timeout 4 | echo ROOT_PASSWORD | sudo -S strace -p 2829 -f -e trace=write -s 9999`

thank you for your help! =)

Comment: Why not just configure sudo to allow password less execution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script that outputs the password, and save it somewhere such as `/home/user/getpass.sh`. Then run this:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=/home/user/getpass.sh sudo -A timeout 4 strace -p 2829 -f -e trace=write -s 9999
```